# Why does (Observable<T>) => Observable<R> resolve as OperatorFunction<T, R>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ng-bootstrap, rxjs-observables

Example code from [ng-bootstrap documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http):

<sup>See the example "Wikipedia search", click on "</> Code" and choose the file "typeahead-http.ts".</sup>

```js
  search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly string[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    )
```

And the definition of `OperatorFunction` from [RxJS documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/OperatorFunction):

```js
interface OperatorFunction<T, R> extends UnaryFunction, Observable> {

  // inherited from index/UnaryFunction
  (source: T): R
}
```

---

Why is it that the type of `search` can be declared as:

- `OperatorFunction<string, string[]>`

which by definition is:

- `(param: string): string[]`

but then assigned to the arrow function with signature

- `(param: Observable<string>): Observable<string[]>`

Shouldn't there be a conflict from attempting to assign `Observable<T>` to `T`? What am I missing here? What is the actual resulting return type of the arrow function `search`?

Comment: Hi. Based on this question, I reported an issue with the `OperatorFunction` docs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6427 Half year later, I managed to figure out where the issue comes from and I created a fixing PR: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/6655
I hope it will get merged soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs page is missing opening `<`.

So `OperatorFunction` is defined as (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.1.0/src/internal/types.ts#L23):

```
export interface OperatorFunction<T, R> extends UnaryFunction<Observable<T>, Observable<R>> {}
```

then `UnaryFunction` is declared as (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.1.0/src/internal/types.ts#L19-L21):

```
export interface UnaryFunction<T, R> {
  (source: T): R;
}
```

This means that `search` is declared as this :

```
(source: Observable<string>): Observable<string[]>;
```

Comment: Heh, you are right. Insepcting the HTML of the doc shows that the first `Observable<T>` gets parsed as HTML which explains why it is visually missing. I was mistakenly thinking that the last `>` is a typo and the interface `extends UnaryFunction, Observable`.